# Расставьте, пожалуйста, знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Когда тихо как было в это утро тишина не нарушается ни движением ни звуком особенно поразительно.

Comment: Слово "расставьте" пишется с мягким знаком.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что д/з.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение нуждается в редактировании (грамматика, стиль), например:

**Когда тихо, как было в это утро,  и тишина не нарушается ни движением ни звуком, то это кажется удивительным.**

Варианты: *кажется удивительным* или  *кажется особенно поразительным* выбираются по контексту.

**Сравнить:** Как хорошо! Тишина удивительная, деревья не шелохнутся.  [П. И. Чайковский. Письма Н. Ф. фон-Мекк (1880)]

Comment: Здесь было бы лучше дать для сравнения цитату из Л.Н. Толстого: _"Когда тихо, как было в это утро, то тишина, не нарушаемая ни движением, ни звуком, особенно поразительна"._ Думаю, что именно это и было в домашнем задании, просто сложно так много слов без ошибок переписать :)

Comment: Я не догадалась, что это цитата из Толстого, думала, что  школьное сочинение. С другой стороны, мне предложение кажется странным: его грамматика,  как мне кажется,. неточно выражает содержание. Здесь должен быть союз И,  так как обозначены два условия: когда тихо и тишина не нарушается.

Comment: Я понимаю основной смысл в таком ключе: "Когда безветренно, то тишина особенно поразительна". (Это не возражение.)

Comment: Смысл  я понимаю так: поразительна абсолютная тишина, не нарушаемая ничем.  Но грамматика этот смысл выражает неточно, союз КОГДА...ТО здесь использован неудачно.